# WPML. После перевода строк некоторые строки все равно выводятся на английском

Tags: wordpress, перевод

Я использую вордпресс с WPML и Woocommerce. Хотя я перевела все нужные строки с помощью String translation, некоторые строки все равно выводятся на английском. Строки оформлены в виде __("string", "woocommerce"). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что такое "String translation"? Какие это "некоторые"? К чему относятся - к теме, плагину?

Comment: @SeVlad Наверное вот это: [String translation](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/)

Comment: @SeVlad это в WPML есть встроенный механизм перевода строк. Она переводит WooCommerce с его помощью. А, может, и свой добавленный код

Comment: @Даниил да, это оно самое

Comment: Покажите пример, что удалось перевести, а что нет. Где находятся "неудачные" вызовы __() ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Даниил, про механизм WPML понял (я этот плаг видел оч. давно), спс. Но зачем переводить WC, он же полностью переведен.

Comment: @SeVlad скорее всего, внесли свои изменения в код, ну и появились новые сообщения, которые хочется правильно перевести.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, в чужом коде мы ничего не правили. Те строки, которые принадлежат лично нам, мы вывели в отдельный .po файл. Проблема в том, что некоторые фразы по умолчанию, которые должен вывести вукомерс, он не выводит. Например, вот тут: http://jevgenija.versija.info/paypal.png Все строки выводит на литовском, а эта строка, например, по-английски.

Comment: Возможно, нет перевода на литовский этой строки. Вы ее переводили с помощью String Translation? Строка находится в файле wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/settings-paypal.php и имеет домен woocommerce. Я смотрю здесь https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce и вижу, что перевод на литовский выполнен на 98%. Скачал оттуда файл перевода wp-plugins-woocommerce-stable-lt.po. Эта строка переведена: Apmokėkite per PayPal. Трудно сказать, в чем у вас дело.

Comment: Да, а файлы woocommerce-lt_LT.po и woocommerce-lt_LT.mo у вас установлены?

Comment: @JevgenijaSinkevič я думаю будет полезны эти ссылки Готовая оф. локализация WC: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce Оф. документация по локализации https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization

Comment: @KAGG Design, да, все установлено. В любом случае, спасибо Вам большое за Ваше время. Будем искать на месте.